# How do I make an image spin under another image?

Tags: html, css

I have two images and I've found css ::after keeps one image on top of the other quite nicely, even when the screen size changes. The thing is I want the image underneath to spin and the image on top to remain stationary. I can't seem to do this and I'm not even sure this is possible using ::after. Is there a way to do it?

Here's my code:

```
    .box {
      display: inline-block;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%; 
      left: 30%;
        -webkit-animation-name: spinnerRotate;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-animation-name: spinnerRotate;
        -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -ms-animation-name: spinnerRotate;
        -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

   .box:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 25px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 25px;
        background: url("../Content/images/top.png");
    }   

<div class="box">
    <img src="../Content/images/bottom.png">
</div>
```

Here's the animation:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-moz-transform:rotate(720deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spinnerRotate
{
    from{-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-ms-transform:rotate(720deg);}
}
```

Comment: Can u post your spinner animation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it like this:

```css
 @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
       transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }


.box::after {
  animation: rotate 5s infinite;
  content:url("http://lorempixel.com/sports/400/200/");
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/">
</div>
```

I changed your `background-image` with using the `content` property. This is not necessary but more comfortable, as you don't need to give the image dimensions.

- Here is a nice article about css animations: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/
- Here is information about compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Comment: Yeah, spinning an image on top of another image is not an issue with ::after. The thing I can't seem to do is spin an image under another image using after. To to that it seems I have to have two different images and then try to keep them lined up even when the screen changes size.

Comment: can you draw a picture or make a demo of what exactly you mean?

Comment: Thanks. Going without ::after seems to be working okay.